# Using :active pseudo class with css transitions?

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-class

i'm making a link where when the link is clicked, it moves down a couple of pixels.
I want this to be an animation so i added css transitions.
Now the problem i'm having is when i press the button, it doesn't complete the animation.
It only animates for as long as i'm holding the mouse button down.

So what i want is that the link completes its animation and after that goes back to the normal position. (This means i can't use :visited because it won't go back to normal).

This is a fiddle i made to clarify my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/SywZV/

This is the code i'm using:

css

```
.button
{
    font-size: 132px;
    font-family: helvetica, sans;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 7px 0px #3b6e62;
    color: #f2b191;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 46px;
    padding-top:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.button:hover {padding-top:3px; text-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #3b6e62;}
.button:active {padding-top:7px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #3b6e62;}
```

html

```
<div class="button">This is a button</div>
```

I'm open to fixing the problem with jquery, however i'm not an expert.

I just figured a way out by using jQuery.
However, i'm not sure it's the right way.
The animation isn't that fluid as with css pseudo classes..

Anyone got something to add on this?

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
      $(this).css({'top': '3px', 'text-shadow': '0px 4px 0px #3b6e62'});
    }); 
    $('.button').click(function(){
      $(this).css({'top': '7px', 'text-shadow': '0px 0px 0px #3b6e62'});
    });  
    $('.button').mouseout(function(){
      $(this).css({'top': '0px', 'text-shadow': '0px 7px 0px #3b6e62'});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know at the moment it's still impossible to bind click events to css.
This work is easily done with Javascript/jQuery.

All you need to do is apply a given class when the element is clicked.
I've just changed the name of one class on your css like so

```
.button-active {padding-top:7px; text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #3b6e62 !important;}
```

And applied it to the div after the element is clicked like so

```
$('.button').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('button-active');
});
```

Take a look at [this](http://jsbin.com/uneden/2) bin.

In my example I'm using jQuery. It is to be noted that if you're going to use it only for this animation you'd better use pure Js, without including a whole library for such a simple effect.

Comment: How would i do this with pure js? Like i said, i'm no expert on jQuery, but you could say i'm a complete newbie to javascript.

Comment: Ps, i've found some sort of solution on my own.. i edited it in my question. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the element when clicked and then, after a delay, remove the class. This in combination with your CSS transitions will achieve the animation effect without requiring the user to keep the mouse button down.

The only change to your CSS was from:

```
.button:active { padding-top: 7px; text-shadow: 0 0 0 #3b6e62; }
```

to (notice the class "pressed" instead of the active pseudo class):

```
.button.pressed { padding-top: 7px; text-shadow: 0 0 0 #3b6e62; }
```

**JavaScript Only**

http://jsfiddle.net/SywZV/8/

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('DIV.button');

    for (var i = 0, max = buttons.length; i < max; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', addPressedClass);
    }

    function addPressedClass(e) {
        var btn = e.target;
        btn.classList.add('pressed');
        setTimeout(function () {
            btn.classList.remove('pressed');
        }, 400);
    }
}, false);
```

**jQuery**

http://jsfiddle.net/SywZV/9/

```
$(function () {
    $('DIV.button').click(function () {
        var $btn = $(this);
        $btn.addClass('pressed');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $btn.removeClass('pressed');
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

I needed to do the same thing while trying to simulate

### Google's Material Button Effect using HTML5 and CSS3:

http://jsfiddle.net/FBDhR/4/

http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-main-buttons